# Time value on VBA Userform changing value to decimal when imputing

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I´m creating a simple userform with VBA/EXCEL, but as soon as I put a time (HH:MM) value onto some fields, they get converted to decimal values.

Is there a way to prevent it from happening?

[Imput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0zcC.jpg)

[Value turns into decimal upon pressing "tab"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TKPt.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a TextBox_Exit event on the form for this field.  Is there formatting or other data manipulation done in that code?

Answer (score 1):

The decimal value you're seeing is the time you input represented in number format expressed as a fractional day.

You'll need to change the format of the cell to one that fits what you expect, or to text.

There are several ways of representing date and time in excel. Take a look at the different number formats in the 'format cells' dialog and pick one that matches what you expect.